# Wireshark dissector encoding for packed BCD

Tags: c++, wireshark

Writing a Wireshark dissector plugin in C++. The protocol I'm trying to parse uses the uncommon packed binary-coded-decimal format for all of its integers.

Normally, when I want to add an item of length `length` at offset `offset`, I write:

```
proto_tree_add_item(body, fields.foo, tvb, offset, length, ENC_LITTLE_ENDIAN);
proto_tree_add_item(body, fields.foo, tvb, offset, length, ENC_NA); // big-endian int
proto_tree_add_item(body, fields.foo, tvb, offset, length, ENC_ASCII); // string
```

... etc. I also need to register the field array with:

```
proto_register_field_array(handle, field_array, array_length(field_array));
```

... where the `field_array` is an array of `hf_register_info`, like this:

```
static hf_register_info field_array[] = {
    { &fields.foo, { "Foo Field", "protocol.foo", FT_UINT48, BASE_DEC } },
    // etc. other fields
};
```

... supposing my example is a 6-byte packed BCD (capable of holding 12 decimal digits).

This all works nicely when I'm parsing sensible protocols that send uint32, ASCII, int64, etc., over the wire. But there appears to be no built-in Wireshark encoding for packed BCDs.

I can see a hacky work-around to parse it as raw data, and then write a function to translate the raw data into the correct value, and then use `proto_item_set_text` to set the item to my desired representation.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular encoding is necessary to make Wireshark display the value nicely. A binary-coded-decimal is like a plain integer, except that the value needs to be translated as if it were decimal.

So `56` (decimal value) for example will be transmitted (assuming big-endian / network-byte-order on the wire) as `0000 0000  0101 0110` or `0056` (hex). All that is needed is to register the field as a FT_UINTX (e.g. UINT32 for 4 byte Packed BCD, UINT40 for 5 byte, etc.) with BASE_HEX representation.

```
static hf_register_info field_array[] = {
    { &fields.foo, { "Foo Field", "protocol.foo", FT_UINT48, BASE_HEX } },
    // etc. other fields
}; // works for 6-byte packed BCD
```

And in the dissecting function itself, add the item:

```
proto_tree_add_item(body, fields.foo, tvb, offset, length, ENC_NA);
```

As for actually turning the BCD bytes into an integer, we can just write a function to transform BCDs to unsigned, e.g.:

```
#include <cstdint>

uint64_t bcd_to_uint(const char* start, const size_t bytes)
{
    uint64_t value = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bytes; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t data = start[i] - '0';
        value += ((data >> 4) * 10 + (data & 0x0f)) * ipow(100, bytes - i - 1);
        // right-shift unsigned will fill with 0s
        // integer promotion will prevent overflow up to UINT_MAX
        // ipow(base, exp) returns base to the power of exp, returns uint64
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`tvb_bcd_dig_to_wmem_packet_str()`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/tvbuff.h;h=52fdb3e862687962fd0c2e36b83175cc8b3f136d;hb=HEAD#l837) would be of use to you?  There are several dissectors that make use of it, which should serve as good examples on how to use it:

```
$ grep -l tvb_bcd_dig_to_wmem_packet_str packet-*.c
```

[`packet-ansi_683.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ansi_683.c;h=ab2a5d0c829aa4661208be97aedba36e887697f0;hb=HEAD#l964)
[`packet-ansi_a.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ansi_a.c;h=0301a008462587f1a5ba1dd82787ad2e885c9251;hb=HEAD#l2380)
[`packet-ansi_map.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ansi_map.c;h=c999f1ce48cc04cf360b39d230f1493d8c596baa;hb=HEAD#l1417)
[`packet-bssap.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-bssap.c;h=85d384527ee5bf5e64d6d2968527c9ee26acbf3f;hb=HEAD#l900)
[`packet-e164.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-e164.c;h=00638ab5c72f3dd76971cb9f3fc8e865119e5554;hb=HEAD#l747)
[`packet-e212.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-e212.c;h=5c72290e71e8c25b12b19f0bcfd5727a9c81a29d;hb=HEAD#l3324)
[`packet-gsm_a_common.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gsm_a_common.c;h=e70bac6b0a735bd64b30ffb2ea0a2e9caca5260a;hb=HEAD#l2153)
[`packet-gsm_a_dtap.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gsm_a_dtap.c;h=93b257b16252eaf23c0590a45e84d4fbe84d6b1d;hb=HEAD#l1186)
[`packet-gsm_map.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gsm_map.c;h=4cc5efad60c0cf33a495ba2ae51b014ee0999e88;hb=HEAD#l3577)
[`packet-gtp.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gtp.c;h=4efc098a422acbe97d098ee52d5c78c1c9b8e1bb;hb=HEAD#l6276)
[`packet-gtpv2.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-gtpv2.c;h=6981bbe75e2119934e9ececeef6c7bf98a82bac5;hb=HEAD#l2009)
[`packet-ilp.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ilp.c;h=44516691a5b3a1d1f0abf37d8d3a82bff40d77ec;hb=HEAD#l775)
[`packet-isup.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-isup.c;h=60d22ea89c88954ad08e654b1c72267e1902c9b5;hb=HEAD#l7151)
[`packet-lte-rrc.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-lte-rrc.c;h=e1c9251a52350518119e4dccea1450afe7cf270d;hb=HEAD#l54602)
[`packet-meta.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-meta.c;h=c652e955a330e5cf14aca599aba58bd388ec9a79;hb=HEAD#l309)
[`packet-mip6.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-mip6.c;h=7485fcadc78a635837883492a3a59fa894ace1aa;hb=HEAD#l1897)
[`packet-nas_eps.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-nas_eps.c;h=b71064dc4fdacd979e8bc0b08603f26d41713aa5;hb=HEAD#l1181)
[`packet-sgsap.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-sgsap.c;h=90da16d8aff3a514f9456a59c98c531ea9db10b2;hb=HEAD#l217)
[`packet-ulp.c`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ulp.c;h=ce380f3fca77e4bc86da5c4eb0cc2bcf9ee30ff2;hb=HEAD#l1291)

Comment: Thanks: it's useful. It saves me having to write my own function to read BCD octets and turn it into a string of digits. However, I'd still have to manually set the text of the proto_tree item. I was wondering if there was something as neat as a special proto_tree_add_* function or some special ENC_PACKED_BCD enum to handle this.

Comment: Of course: I see it now. Packed BCDs are perfectly readable as raw hexadecimals, as long as the human reader reads them as decimals. Will write up an answer.

Comment: The problem with this function is that it takes first low half of byte and then high half. 0x12 is translated to "21".